# Multiple search json call

Tags: json

I've an search that does an ajax call on a json file with information. Visitors can multiple search on items of that information, but i can't create that multiple search. When a visitor search on information they only get result on one of their search filters.

You can search on:

- name
- date
- city

  ```
  function getEventsByName(key, value)
  {
   $.ajax({
       dataType: 'json',
       url: '...',
       success : function(data)
       {
          var events = JSON.stringify(data);
          var filter = getObjects(data, key, value);

          $("#block-a-events").empty();

          $.each($.uniqueSort(filter), function(i, item) {

              content += '</div>';
              etc...
              $("#block-a-events").append(content);

          })
       }
   })     
  }
  ```

Above you find the call to the json file.
Before the information 'll show. I'll filter the information in **getObjects()**

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) 
{
 var objects = [];
 for (var i in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
        objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
    } else if (i.includes(key) && obj[key].includes(val)) {
        objects.push(obj);
    }
 }
 return objects;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can someone give an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The key to your search is indexOf